# XQuery fn:deep-equal - comparing text from XPath with string literal

Tags: xquery, saxon

I'm trying to use XQuery function **fn:deep-equal** to compare sections of XML documents and I'm getting unexpected behaviour. When comparing XPath value with string literal, function returns false.

For example following code

```
let $doc :=
  <root>
    <child><message>Hello</message></child>
  </root>

let $message := <message>Hello</message>

let $value := $doc/child/message/text()
let $compareDirectly := fn:deep-equal($value, "Hello") (: -> false :)
let $compareAsString := fn:deep-equal(fn:concat($value, ""), "Hello") (: -> true :)
let $comparePath := fn:deep-equal($value, $message/text()) (: -> true :)

return
  <results>
    <value>{$value}</value>
    <directly>{$compareDirectly}</directly>
    <asString>{$compareAsString}</asString>
    <path>{$comparePath}</path>
  </results>
```

Executed using Saxon, XQuery program  generates following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <value>Hello</value>
    <directly>false</directly>
    <asString>true</asString>
    <path>true</path>
</results>
```

I'd expect $compareDirectly to be true (same as two other examples), but fn:deep-equal does not seem to work as I would intuitively expect. I'm wondering whether this is correct behaviour.

Is there any better wah how to compare two XML nodes?

I'm lookig for some generic solution which could be used for both XML snippets (like values of $doc or $message in example) and also for this special case with string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-deep-equal):

> To be deep-equal, they must contain items that are pairwise deep-equal; and for two items to be deep-equal, they must either be atomic values that compare equal, or nodes of the same kind, with the same name, whose children are deep-equal.

So this is why it doesn't return true when comparing a text node to an atomic type. In your other two examples you are comparing 2 string atomic types. It looks as if you don't need deep-equal, which compares nodes recursively. If that's the case, then you can just compare the strings:

```
$doc/child/message/string() eq $message/string()
=> true()
```

If there are other requirements, then you may need to update your example to demonstrate those more clearly.

Comment: I'm trying to write generic function which compares to nodes from XML document (like values of $doc or $message) in example and this works fine.

My issue with fn:deep-equal($value, "Hello")  is somehow special case, but I need to cover this as well. I did not want to add example of comparing nodes because it works as expected, and I'm trying to keep example simple but still executable.

Comment: It is not a special case, as you are doing the equivalent of `deep-equal(text{"Hello"},"Hello")`, which compares a text node to a string atomic type. As these are different types of data, deep equal is false. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, your explanation makes sense. My commennt was bit misleading - it's special case just from my perspective, as I'm usually comparing nodes, not atomic value, but it's just my way of using it.

You example actually helped to solve my problem, thanks pointing the difference in types. Originally I was trying to use "...message/text()". If I change my example to use "message/string()" code does what I expect.

Comment: @ArnostValicek Right, text() can be tricky - it selects the sequence of text nodes, which is often not what people want. Text may appear continuous but actually be made up of multiple text nodes. i.e.: `let $t := (text{this },text{ is some },text{text.}) return count($t/text()) => 3`